# Different timers for different rooms using Socket.io

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

I found 3 other posts about implementing timers for turn based games but none of them had a final answer.

I am working on a poker game project using WebSockets (Socket.io) rooms.

Each room has a timer which takes care of the turns from the server, for example, each player has 10 seconds to choose a card. If there was only one room I was able to do this by using setInterval and changing the turn variable at the end of each interval and emit the new turn to the clients.

But right now, I am confused how to implement a specific timer for each room when there are a lot of rooms considering that node.js is single threaded.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Despite being single threaded, Node.js can manage multiple timers at once. You can just set them. How you do it is up to you. Keep in mind that you'll need to use `bind` if you're managing your `Room`s with objects. You can use variables to manage (for example, cancelling) your timers.

Here is a general example:

```
var Room = function() {
  this.id = String(Date.now());
  this.timer = setInterval(this.timerFunction.bind(this), 10000);
}

Room.prototype.timerFunction = function() {
  // Example
  io.to(this.id).emit("some message");
}

// Create one
new Room();
```

Comment: Thanks, this is great! I have an off-topic question now. Is it safe to save all the information of the rooms (like players' names, turn and round numbers) in classes like Room in the above example? Isn't it too much overhead in the server? Do I need to save such data in mongodb also?

Comment: @nOp No problem! MongoDB is only used if you need to store data permanently, that can be accessed later or by other servers. It's ok for any data that is temporary to exist only in variables (such as in an object structure). Even if you do store data in a database, you still need to store that data for use in the code. By the way, you'll probably need to store these objects in an array. In terms of overhead, the number of rooms you can handle depends on how well you've written the code, and the performance of the computer on which it is running (among other factors).